# django. need hints for web develepment

Tags: python, django, url, web

I am a new guy in a web development. I have some experience with django already. But it was simple site with a couple of forms. And I want to continue with django. And now I have an idea what I would like to see alive and need some hints, advises, right directions. I do not know what "right words" should I use for a search request and I hope you will help me with that. I do not need ready made solutions I just need starting point.

The idea is that I want to implement web service where user can create his own simple web-site with a couple of pages with ready made templates. So, there are two question:

1) User should get his own url automatically after registration. For example I have LAMP and my domain is example.com. User will get user_name.example.com. I saw similar implementation so this is not impossible. But how server can handle it? Is it made by django, apache or something else?

2) User should have his own admin page, like user_name.example.com/admin. It can be django-admin page but available only for that user or it can be any page what I will make for him. On that page he can modify content of his pages. In the end I will get structure like that:

```
    user_1.example.com
        user_1.example.com/page_1
        user_1.example.com/page_2

    user_2.example.com
        user_2.example.com/page_1
        user_2.example.com/page_2
```

So, how those technique could call to search? I appreciate any help from you!

P.S. Of course, I can not reject your help if you will provide some code, tutorials or examples =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Django, you must use its main advantage - the larger community:

1. http://github.com/ennio/django-hosts (As already mentioned, you can identify the user by domain using middleware)
2. Use django admin with this: https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian.
   You can assign the necessary permissions to change pages as this example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Answer (score 0):

1. The web server is responsible for which domain names it serves. You will need to write middleware to extract the username from the hostname though.
2. Django's admin pages only go so far. If you want separation by user then I recommend you implement them independently (although reusing some of the classes Django's admin tools provide can't hurt).